# Generating random variable from no closed-form marginal density using r or other programming language

Tags: random-variables, nonlinear-optimization, monte-carlo, simulation, gaussian

Suppose $U\sim N(0,I_p)$, $Y|U\sim N(x(t),\sigma_e^2I_m)$, and the marginal distribution of $Y$ is $f(y)=\int_u f(y|u)f(u)du$.

$x(t)$ is composite function of $U$, basically $x(t)$ is a function of $z(t)$ and $z(t)$ is a function of $U$. I can provide the expression of $x(t)$ in terms of $U$, it's too complicated(involves exponent terms, integrand in dinominator), but I feel it's probably unnecessary. Another info is that the marginal pdf of $y$ has no-closed form expression.

I think what I need to do is generate random variable from $f(y)$, I am reading Monte Carlo method textbook, but there is no detail or probably I am newbie about generating random variable. The textbook is giving an example of normal mixture and the example is given https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions here too, but it's not similar what I am dealing with.

I have also seen this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508216/how-to-generate-data-from-cdf-which-is-not-in-closed-form?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466959/multivariate-and-marginal-simulations, but still so confused. The fact is how do I assume the distribution(marginal distribution) of $y$. Or do I need to go for indirect method (eg. accept-reject method)?

Like in the last link they are telling to generate $y_1^{(1)}$ from $f(y_1)$ first. But how do I do that if I don't know the $f(y_1)$

I want to implement the algorithm in r, but I am stuck at the very beginning of making the algorithm.

Comment: Would it not be correct to generate $U$, plug it into $x(t)$, then generate $Y$?

Comment: @Stacker can you give  little detail, exactly not getting it. I am telling what I understand  1. first, generate u from standard normal  2. plug the generating u and get x(t). 3. Since we know x(t), so we can generate random variable from f(y|u) 4. Now what? After that  how to generate y from that  f(y|u) since f(y|u) is not f(y). Should we like the multiply the u value and value from f(y|u), probably the last line is a dumb question.

Comment: @Stacker Also if you can provide me the code of any programming, I might understand what it is.

Comment: Yes that is the correct procedure. Generating $U$ and then generating from $Y|U$ will have the effect of generating from $f(y)$. Study the graphic in the third link to confirm. All you will need is `library(MASS)` and `mvrnorm` as well as to write some code for vectors, matrices, and computing $x(t)$. Do you need help with that too?

Comment: @Stacker, thanks. I think I can probably do that, although it might take time. But this is the last question, since multiplying is giving us the joint distribution, not the marginal. Will that value is right for $y$ or I need to integrate with respect to u(here I am confused, if I need to integrate, how exactly? also, how to do integrate part(if I need) in r?

Comment: You don’t need to figure out the pdf of $Y$. Discard the $U$ after you use it to generate from $Y|U$.

Comment: @Stacker so just to make sure, multiplying value is the generating value of y that we can use for further procedure?

Comment: Multiply what with what?

Comment: @Stacker Generate u from f(U) and  another random variable (say v) from f(Y|U). So multiplying u and v will generate the y value i.e y=u*v ?

Comment: No no no the y value is just v. Throw away the u after each iteration and don’t multiply u and v. Just store v in a vector every iteration

Comment: @Stacker, ok thank you so much, I know I shouldn't thank you in the comment, but I can't upvote you for being a new user.

Comment: Not a problem, good luck with it